# MySQL query with if condition

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I've 2 tables: A device table and a User table.

Device Table has 2 columns: ID, and MacAddress. 
User Table has 4 columns: ID, Name, Phone, MacAddress.

There will be a fixed list populating the User Table for example:

1, Steve Marks, 219-373-1485, 5A:2B:3C:8D

2, Dan Marks, 310-248-1455, 5C:3A:2B:8A

Every 5 mins the device table will be populated with MacAddresses and device information within the local vicinity.

I want to create a view such that gets the name, phone of  MacAddresses that are repeated more than twice in the device table and if there is a corresponding macaddress match in the User table.

Thanks!

Sam

Comment: How familiar are you with SQL? Have you written queries with JOINs before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understood your Users table contains all users of a WLAN hotspot for example. And the device list containts all mac addresses having accessed the hotspot at a given time.

What about

```
SELECT name, macAddress, count(macAddress)
FROM Device
    INNER JOIN USER ON User.MacAddress = Device.MacAddress
GROUP BY name, macAddress
HAVING COUNT(macAddress) >= 2
```

If I understood your usecase right, I'd advice adding another timestamp column to the device table. So you are prepared for the data to change and are able to select within desired time periods. E.g. "who had at least 2 times access between 10 and 11 o'clock?":

```
SELECT name
FROM Device 
    INNER JOIN USER ON User.MacAddress = Device.MacAddress
WHERE timestamp between '2016-02-14 10:00:00' and '2016-02-14 11:00:00'
GROUP by name, macAddress
HAVING COUNT(macAddress) >= 2
ORDER BY name
```

Comment: Thanks everyone for your input...dsteinkopf's answer worked for me..Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use this query

```
SELECT name,phone, MacAddress, COUNT(name) as total
FROM user
GROUP BY name
HAVING ( COUNT(name) > 1 )
```

Comment: Missing a requirement: "I want to create a view such that gets the name, phone of MacAddresses that are repeated more than twice in the device table _and if there is a corresponding macaddress match in the User table_"

Comment: Not sure if the syntax are right but try somthing like this:                       SELECT MacAddress,name,phone  
FROM Device as d
join User as u
group by MacAddress
COUNT(d.MacAddress)
HAVING ( COUNT(d.MacAddress) > 1 )

Answer (score 0):

You can use this query to find name and phone matching macaddresses repeated more than two times into Device table and its corresponding mac address found into User table.

```
select D1.Name, D1.Phone D1.MacAddress from User U 
 join ( 
    select MacAddress from Device 
      group by MacAddress 
     having count(MacAddress) > 2 ) D on U.MacAddress = D.MacAddress
 join Device D1 on D1.MacAddress = D.MacAddress
```

If you need to find it more than 1 time, simple change to

```
count(MacAddress) >= 2
```